# SQL Statement - CHARINDEX Invalid Function

Tags: sql, hive, instr

I want to split a string and get the value after the space and am using below query. However i am getting an error that CHARINDEX is not valid. Are there any ways i can get around this?[image]

```
SELECT  productname,
SUBSTRING(productname, instr(' ', productname) +9, 50) AS ShortProductName       
FROM   ar_cem_financedb_analytics_finance.dimproduct
```

Comment: It depends on the DBMS you're using. Is it SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive does not support SQL Server's `CHARINDEX()` function.

In your 2nd query you are using `INSTR()` but the arguments are reversed.
Change to:

```
SUBSTRING(productname, instr(productname, ' ') +9, 50)
```

or use `LOCATE()`:

```
SUBSTRING(productname, locate(' ', productname) +9, 50)
```